# How to check if a jar is Multi-Release

Tags: java, jar, manifest, java-9, java-module

Separating this out of the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662286/error-log4j-api-2-9-0-jar-is-a-multi-release-jar-file-but-multi-release-optio) that I had, assuming this to be generic enough. How can I prior to using an artifact check if it is a multi-release jar.

```
Multi-Release: true
```

I know its possible looking manually into the `MANIFEST.MF` within the `META-INF` of the jar for the above attribute, but is there a command line option available for this?

Maybe I am missing something already existing with some other name or blind to something very obvious. But I tried looking out for such an option in [`jar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jar.htm#JSWOR614) and 
[`java`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624) tool as well to no success.

Comment: When I looked for a way to peek into a JARs manifest, I found no solution either. I think there's no way around [unzipping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662468/2525313).

Comment: Nicolai is correct, the `jar` tool does not provide options to quickly see if a JAR file is a MR JAR. The simplest is to use `jar --file=<file> --list` and look for META-INF/versions in the list. Yes, there is a corner case where someone adds a version section without the Multi-Release attribute in the manifest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jar only supports special operations on the manifest file during creation and updating. You can get by with this:

```
unzip -p file.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep "Multi-Release: true"
```

Other than that, JarFile includes the following new method that could be useful:

boolean [isMultiRelease](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#isMultiRelease--)(): Return true when this JAR file is a multi-release JAR file.

Comment: Maybe you should add that this only works on Linux. :)