# LogManager.getLogger() is unable to determine class name on Java 11

Tags: java, log4j2, java-11

I'm using log4j2 (2.11.1) with Java 11 and attempting to get a `Logger` object using:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();
```

(Imported from `log4j-api` in `org.apache.logging.log4j`)

At runtime, I receive the following error:

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No class provided, and an appropriate one cannot be found.
at 
org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.callerClass(LogManager.java:555)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:580)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:567)
    at app.App.<clinit>(App.java:11)
```

Which does make sense - getCallerClass is not supported and so the logger is unable to determine the class name.

Is it supposed to work this way? Surely I don't have to hard-code the class name into each logger?

Comment: There's been some "clean up" in the Java API and underlying system code.  My guess is something that used to work doesn't anymore, and the Apache folks haven't got around to fixing it.  I don't know what you can do other than downgrade to an earlier version of Java or use a different log manager.

Comment: Could you be precise over which dependency of `log4j2 (2.11.1)`?

Comment: It's log4j-api - edited question to include

Comment: @markspace wow, really? One of the most popular logging frameworks isn't compatible with current LTS of Java?

Comment: @DanielScott I find that third party efforts to outdo [existing standard functionality](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) tend to believe their “clever” hacks are what make them superior.  I don’t share their belief.

Comment: The official API, [`StackWalker.getCallerClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html#getCallerClass()), has been introduced with Java 9. According to [the changelogs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.9.0), support for it has been added even in log4j2 2.9.0. Perhaps, you need a build specifically for Java 9+…

Comment: When I download pre-built binaries from https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html I get multi-release jars, which will automatically select the implementation version when running under Java 9 or newer. So the crucial point is how the version, you are using, has been built.

Comment: @Holger is right mostly, seems like you're not using the library under java9+ which is where the [updated implementation of StackLocator](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-api-java9/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.java) is. Not able to share a screenshot here in the comments, but the MR-JAR of log4j includes a different implementation of StackLocator at `../.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar!/META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class`

Comment: Yep, I have that class file in my dependency... still not working though

Comment: And the file is identical to the one in the same location in my shaded jar

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The reason was that the multi-release class files were not being picked up from `META-INF/versions/*` because I hadn't set the multi-release flag when I built my shaded jar.

I needed to add:

```
Multi-Release:true
```

To my manifest, and everything started working.

Comment: Yep, I shouldn't have forgotten as well that [log4j is a multi-release jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662286/)

Comment: @Daniel - Can you expand on that? Which manifest did you add that line to? I don't get what "shaded jar" is.

Comment: A 'shared' jar is a jar which repackages your code with it's dependencies. It's the manifest in this jar which contains the additional line

Comment: @DanielScott so every jar which calls logmanager getlogger should be a multi-release jar if it uses log4j 2.11?

Comment: Best to test that yourself, but I expect that as long as the jar you've built is multi-release and it includes log4j it should be fine

Comment: @DanielScott this solution still not working with jdk14 and log4j2 (2.13.2) . I tried to insert  the  property in the manifest Multi-Release:true as property but the same error appear. There same changes with the new log4j2 ?

Comment: Are you certain it's present in the manifest? Did you unpack the jar to check?

Answer (score 14):

The answer by @DanielScott is correct. When using the Gradle Shadow plugin, I added the following to my `build.gradle` to appended the `Multi-Release:true` flag to the manifest.

```java
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Multi-Release': 'true'
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, running on Amazon Corretto 15.

Comment: Same thing on Maven can be accomplished by adding `<manifestEntries><Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release></manifestEntries>` in the `<archive>` tag of your `pom.xml`